# ASP.Net Menu on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the Menu Control in Visual Studio 2010 is set up horizontal in my Master page but on same pages when the page loads and on postback with datasources that take a few seconds to return data the menu spreads vertically down the page. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.  can't post the image yet but here i sthe URL to see what happens http://mdreflexology.com/RobVoreResume/images/MenuOnPageLoad.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try and use the ASP.net data cache.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="myMenu" %>
```

See here for more information: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111708/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121306-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. I read another post that had the same issue and used the CSS menu adapter. Doe sit work with VS 2010 and framework 4.0 along with the sitemap?

Comment: I tried it in th emaster page but it's not allowed. Also trie dit in the Page that is having a problem and it did effect it. Darmn I thought this might work. I tried the VaryByParam with None then * then the id of the menu control.